# Two Json lists in one spinner using else statement

Tags: android, json, spinner

In my app I have 2 spinners they are populated with JSON data pulled from a file on my company server.
The spinners are populated if a correct `email`, `password` and `clientID` is entered.
Now I want to add that if the details are wrong or non exist they must show a different JSON.

I am trying to do this by calling an else if statement in my `onResponse` method.

To summarize
I want each spinner to show a JSON data array with categories/client details in if the login information is entered/correct (this works but I was asked to add this second array for errors) and if there is missing/incorrect information it must show the the JSON array with the errors in. Both JSON arrays are in the same file.

I believe my problem lies with my adapter, as it is calling one `ArrayList` is it possible to let it call both array lists heres the adapter, I want to add a second `ArrayList` to this, the current one is "CategoryName"

```
  spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(SecondActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, CategoryName));
```

**CODE FOR LOADING THE SPINNERS DATA**

```
private void loadSpinnerData(String url) {

    RequestQueue requestQueue=Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {


            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);

                if (jsonObject.getInt("success") == 1) {

                    JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("Name");
                    for (int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject1=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        String category=jsonObject1.getString("Category");
                        CategoryName.add(category);
                    }
                }
                if (jsonObject.getInt("failed") == 1) {
                    JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("errors");
                    for (int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject1=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        String error=jsonObject1.getString("reason");
                        Errors.add(error);


                    }
                }
                spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(SecondActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, CategoryName));


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    int socketTimeout=30000;
    RetryPolicy policy=new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);

    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: You can Define your own adapter by extending Arrayadapter.

Comment: @Rajnishsuryavanshi , I have been coding for a total of 3 weeks, can you elaborate please, Must I make a custom adapter or what must I do, I tried to check tutorials but I don't understand them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply have to use your `Errors` `ArrayList`. Currently you add the information to it (in your second `if` branch) but never put it into the spinner.

Try this:

```
JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);

if (jsonObject.getInt("success") == 1) {
    JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("Name");
    for (int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject1=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

        String category=jsonObject1.getString("Category");
        CategoryName.add(category);
    }
    spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(SecondActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, CategoryName));
}

if (jsonObject.getInt("failed") == 1) {
    JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("errors");
    for (int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject1=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

        String error=jsonObject1.getString("reason");
        Errors.add(error);

    }
    spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(SecondActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, Errors));
}
```

Comment: The Spinners are not populating with this, any advice??